# float 4 function in visual studio 2012 [c++]

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2012

I'm starting to learn directx 11 programming, but I stopped when I see in code float4 function.
My VS 2012 send me an error that that function isn't really exist. 
(Identifier "float4" is undefined)

In my book there is nothing about my problem.

Please help me what should I do? May I need to change something in properties of program or project?

That's my code.

```
float4 VS_Main(float4 pos : POSITION) : SV_POSITION
{
    return pos;
}
```

One more time please, help me...

Comment: Looks like you need to [learn about HLSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509561(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910067/starting-setup-directx-with-visual-studio-2012-for-desktop

Comment: I just found that James: http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html
It's gonna be a long long night... :) Thanks!